# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library which might have disabled stack guard

Tags: java, eclipse, debian, libpcap, shared-libraries

can any one help me with this error message .

while try to compile project in eclipse using jNetpcap API

I followed all the steps mentioned on the website below ,how to setup the environment on Debian distribution

http://jnetpcap.com/compile/debian

though I still get the following error message

> choosedevice ...  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded
>   library        /usr/lib/libjnetpcap.so.1.3.b0003 which might have
>   disabled stack guard. The VM will try to   fix the stack guard now.
>   It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c
>   ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'. Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /usr/lib/libjnetpcap.so.1.3.b0003: /usr/lib/libjnetpcap.so.1.3.b0003:
>   mauvaise classe ELF : ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word
>   width mismatch)   at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)    at
>   org.jnetpcap.Pcap.(Unknown Source)    at
>   main.Main_app.choosedevice(Main_app.java:74)  at
>   main.Main_app.main(Main_app.java:273)

By the way I tried to execute " execstac -c " it doesn't work at all
Also I spent days trying to figure out the solution , the only conclusion i come up with so far , is i need to use libjnetpcap.so (64 bit) since i have 64 bit architecture on my Debian .
so is that what i need to do ?

PS : I can't find any ".deb" to install this library for 64 bit.

Comment: If you want to use a 32 bit native library, you must use a 32 bit jvm.

Comment: is there any other solution ? using JVM 64 bit

Comment: Get 64 bit version of the native library - check in `/usr/lib64` rather than `/usr/lib`.

Comment: You may need to check your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. If you are running with a 64 bit jvm, then `/usr/lib` should not be part of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `/usr/lib64` should be.

Comment: @BrettOkken: I have a similar issue in RHEL running 32-bit libraries. How can I use a 32 bit JVM on RHEL 7?

Comment: @BrettOkken make sure you are using the right library. since you have 32 JVM, you should use 32 bit Lib.

Answer (score 0):

What does the file  `/usr/lib/libjnetpcap.so.1.3.b0003` contain?

If the file is a **0-byte-file**, there is something really wrong, so try to repair your system by reinstalling that library.

I had the same problem in smartgit, where a library in the local config folder was used, which was somehow corrupted and was a 0 byte file. So deleting the config folder and restarting the app worked for me. This could be a solution here too.